# OpenSMTPD: every local mails to a specific destination

Tags: mail-transport-agent

I currently use Exim for the following need, and it works well. But too much hassle when upgrading because this is a hack which require modifying files we are not supposed to.
I try with OpenSMTPD because it seems simple for my need, but I'm stuck. Any other software is okay as long it is into the Debian repository.

The needs:

- the MTA listen only on 127.0.0.1 (easy)
- it is intended to collect **every** mails originating from the local machine (from cron or whatever), and send them to a specific **external** recipient (dest@example.com) overriding the original recipient
- in case of network failure the mails are sent later, which is not possible with [esmtp](http://esmtp.sourceforge.net/) for example
- no need to maintain an aliases file when a user is created/destroyed
- bonus: if an external recipient is already present (or more than one), then send the mail to it AND to dest@example.com (i.e. replace any local recipient with dest@example.com)

With OpenSMTPD I tested to use wildcard into the alisases file, but this doesn't work.
Maybe I need to modify /etc/smtpd.conf but I don't see how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing `genericstable` support in the `smtpd.conf` after some digging around; an attempt at a table rewrite on relay resulted in an `aliases/virtual may not be used with a relay rule` error. You can say `accept from local for local relay as "user@example.com"` but that does not appear to rewrite the addresses in the message, only the sender in the SMTP session.

See perhaps [Postfix Root email forwarding to external address as bcc only](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413696/postfix-root-email-forwarding-to-external-address-as-bcc-only/413703#413703) to do this from postfix.